# Create Hard Link to a Directory (OS X)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I need to make a hard link to a directory in OS X, but I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.x, so [some options that worked no longer do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432540/creating-directory-hard-links-in-macos-x). Any suggestions?

**Note:** I'm using this to get the same source in multiple GIT repositories.

Comment: Hardlinks to directories are a bad idea to begin with, and using it to futz with git repositories like that makes it sound even worse.

Comment: SVN supports "externals", perhaps something similar exists for git?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, it surely sounds bad. I'm open to alternatives in GIT, if you know any....

Comment: This question was just bumped to the front page. Any news? How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Hard links to directories were added to HFS+ specifically to support Time Machine backups. However, most utilities do not expect them, and you should probably avoid using them yourself.

It sounds like you might be in a situation where you would benefit from using [Git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html). A submodule allows one Git repository to maintain a link to another repository. For example if your project builds a copy of libcoolstuff as part of it's own build, your directory might look like this:

```
|- /MyProject
    |-- .git/
    |
    |-- libcoolstuff/
    |   |-- libcoolstuff.c
    |   |-- libcoolstuff2.c
    |
    |-- mysource.c
    |-- ...
```

In this case, you might want to have libcoolstuff be a submodule:

```
git submodule add /path/to/repo/libcoolstuff libcoolstuff
```

This will create a subdirectory called `libcoolstuff` in your MyProject repo.  The link between `libcoolstuff` and the original repo it came from is maintained, and it can be updated in MyProject as updates are committed in the source repo.

In your situation, perhaps you have a project which you want to become a part of multiple other projects, and stay current with their development. This will let you do that, as long as all the projects are maintained in their own Git repos.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. I think I'm talking about something else, though perhaps not. I have a file folder that is NOT physically (?) within the GIT repo (not a subfolder of the folder that has the .git file), but I want its contents to be under source control. This would allow strange things such as one directory showing up in several GIT repos at once via hard links.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I changed my answer to discuss submodules; is this more in line with what you're trying to do?